# Is it possible to season chicken breast with BBQ sauce before baking it in the oven?

Tags: baking, barbecue, seasoning, chicken-breast

I always put BBQ sauce on my chicken after it is done baking, but I was wondering if I can do the same *while* seasoning it to save time?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, and should try it.

Baking the chicken with the sauce will cook the sauce and will start caramelize some of the sauce making the chicken better (IMO).

Comment: ... but you don't get any browning on the chicken, so it's a trade-off.  (you also reduce the risk of over-cooking the outside of the chicken, and can always scrape off the sauce if it burns).  I've seen quite a few recipes that call for adding the sauce part-way through cooking, so you can get the best of both methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "It is possible"...however there are trade offs. The sauce will caramelize and become a tasty glaze...but...your chicken becomes more 'braised'(cooked in liquid) than 'grilled'. You get the caramelized sauce but loose the '[maillard effect](http://modernistcuisine.com/2013/03/the-maillard-reaction/)' that comes from grilling. As taste is personal matter the best advise is try it and see which you and your audience prefer.

On an aside, you might try doing a brine (long soak) or marinade (other than the viscous BBQ sauce, for instance soy sauce) and/or even injections to layer different flavors.

Comment: You can do both. You start off by char grilling the chicken on a high heat, then baste the sauce on in the last few minutes of cooking on a lower heat. It gives you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Advantage is moister chicken, more tender chicken with a baked glaze on it. Seals the skin it will.  I often rub  a chicken inside & out with a wild honey& BBQ dry mix. Yard hens. If over baked at most all you need remove is the skin to discard.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, people make baby back ribs this way by gradually adding layers of BBQ sauce on the meat. You'll eventually get a good layer of sauce coating the meat.